# SonarQube 6.7 freezes on login

Tags: sonarqube

I have just installed SonarQube 6.7 on an Ubuntu 16.04 server with MySQL 5.7.; SonarQube is used by my colleagues, who added their projects from their source code hosted on GitHub repositories.

After that 3-4 projects have been added, we started encountering a problem when opening SonarQube with Chrome on MacOS (both on the latest version): as soon as an user logs in, the SonarQube dashboard freezes and no data is loaded, no reaction when clicking on any link, no error on the browser's console, no relevant error in SonarQube log or Apache log.

It looks like working fine on Firefox on Windows 10 though.

The only workaround is opening another page of SonarQube on a separate tab (like sonarqube.mydomain.com/admin or sonarqube.mydomain.com/about) and from there it works and the users can browse everything.

As the port 9000 is closed on the server from outbound, we have set up a proxy with Apache, which redirects the HTTP traffic (port 80) to HTTPS (port 443) and then to SonarQube (port 9000). As test we opened the port 9000 from outbound, but we still encounter the bug if we log in from sonarqube.mydomain.com:9000; therefore the Apache proxy should not be the problem.

Do you have an idea, what the problem could be? Which other logs should I check, in your opinion?

I thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: When the web page freeze, could you have a look at the web console ?

Comment: Unfortunately the browser's web console stays empty and I cannot even find any pending request in the _Network_ tab.

Comment: Then it sounds more like a proxy issue than a SonarQube issue...

Comment: In my original question I wrote that "As test we opened the port 9000 from outbound, but we still encounter the bug if we log in from sonarqube.mydomain.com:9000; therefore the Apache proxy should not be the problem." I don't think that it's a proxy issue, as I still encounter the problem after excluding the proxy. What else do you suggest?