# SonarQube 6.7.1 freezes on login

Tags: sonarqube

This appears to be the same issue as [SonarQube 6.7 freezes on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150964/sonarqube-6-7-freezes-on-login)

On mac with Chrome 64 (other browsers don't seem to be affected), with a fresh instead of SonarQube. If I go to the home page (projects?sort=-analysis_date) the page will load everything except the project and end up frozen. (The tab in Chrome itself will be frozen, right click won't work). After 30-60 seconds chrome will have the pop up asking if you want to wait or kill the page.

I tried seeing if anything appear in inspect but i saw no error. If i enter SonarQube from different pages (project pages, admin pages) it works without issue. The freezing only appear on the home page, on mac with chrome 64.

[image]

Comment: No errors in the console tab?

Comment: None. The page (and only if i land on it first) seem to freeze. What i do see the following. When i got to chrome Performance, tab and run it while the page is stuck i see Rasterizer thread 4 is constantly running (repainting). When I go a different way to this page none o Rasterizer thread are stuck constantly repainting. 

I can send you screen shots of both working (with no repainting) and with the issue (constantly repainting)

Comment: try to remove the `sonarqube.*` items from the browser local storage

Comment: Clearing out local storage did not fix the problem for me.  Still unresolved. Appears to be chrome only as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is still a problem in 7.1. It does not happen on Safari.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but using chrome on private mode it works fine.